# Ajax redirect not performed

Tags: jquery, ajax

Data is persisting in table but after that page is not redirected to the specified destination.

Is redirection through ajax possible?

Please check the code and help me out

```
function foodLog(){
    var getDate = $('#ddBox').val();
    var stringDate = getDate;
    var newdate = stringDate.split("/").reverse().join("-");
    var data={ 
        servings : $('#demo_vertical').val(),
        calories : "12",
        carbs : $('#carbs').text(),
        carter : $('#carter').text(),
        cholestral : $('#cholestral').text(),
        date: newdate,  
        fiber : $('#fiber').text(),
        foodItem: $('#foodItem').text(),
        foodtype:$('#foodtype').text(),
        totalFat : $('#totalFat').text(),
        saturatedFat : $('#satFat').text(),
        sugar : $('#sugar').text(),
        protein: $('#protein').text(),
        size :$('#size').text(),
    };

    $.ajax({  
        type : "POST",   
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url : "/fitbase/foodlog/create",
        dataType: "text",
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        success : function(response) {

            if (response.redirect){
                console.log("Redirecting to page") 
                window.location.href = '/'; 
            }
        },
        error : function(e) {  
            alert("Object" +e);
        }  
    });  
};
```

Comment: is the `console.log` occurring? i mean is `response.redirect` true?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea No its not printing

Comment: try : `window.location = '/';`

Comment: Since you specify `dataType: "text"`, `response` will be a string, not an object. So `response.redirect` makes no sense.

Comment: that means you aren't getting a response. the real question isn't "why isn't this redirecting", its "why am i not getting the anticipated response". try doing `console.log(response)` to see what object you get back. edit: did not notice you had `dataType:'text'`, yeah that'll muck it up.

Comment: @Barmar Then what is the best solution?

Comment: Return JSON instead of a string.

Comment: @Barmar I gave JSON on dataType then also not redirecting

Comment: Is the server script returning JSON?

Comment: in console.log(response), its returning my method return type which is boolean "true" but not getting json response

Answer (score 0):

I think window.location.href should contain the entire redirection url instead of '/' in your code.

Comment: You can use relative URLs there.